# confusing python urlencode order

Tags: python, urlencode

okay, so according to http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html

"The order of parameters in the encoded string will match the order of parameter tuples in the sequence."

except when I try to run this code:

```
import urllib
values ={'one':'one',
         'two':'two',
         'three':'three',
         'four':'four',
         'five':'five',
         'six':'six',
         'seven':'seven'}
data=urllib.urlencode(values)
print data
```

outputs as ...

```
seven=seven&six=six&three=three&two=two&four=four&five=five&one=one
```

7,6,3,2,4,5,1?

That doesn't look like the order of my tuples.

Comment: You aren't passing a sequence of tuples.  Since you're not passing a sequence of tuples, why are you quoting the documentation for a sequence of tuples?

Answer (score 27):

Dictionaries are inherently unordered because of the way they are implemented. If you want them to be ordered, you should use a list of tuples instead (or a tuple of lists, or a tuple of tuples, or a list of lists...):

```
values = [ ('one', 'one'), ('two', 'two') ... ]
```

Answer (score 6):

Just in case someones arrives here like me searching for a way to get deterministic results from `urlencode`, to encode the values alphabetically you can do it like this:

```
from urllib.parse import urlencode
values ={'one':'one',
         'two':'two',
         'three':'three',
         'four':'four',
         'five':'five',
         'six':'six',
         'seven':'seven'}
sorted_values = sorted(values.items(), key=lambda val: val[0])
data=urlencode(sorted_values)
print(data)
#> 'five=five&four=four&one=one&seven=seven&six=six&three=three&two=two'
```

Comment: Look at the printed result, since when is that ordered?

Comment: @RenatoDamas ? It's alphabetical.

Answer (score 1):

Why not using `OrderedDict`? Your code would then look like this:

```py
from collections import OrderedDict
from urllib.parse import urlencode

d = OrderedDict()
d['one'] = 'one'
d['two'] = 'two'
d['three'] = 'three'
d['four'] = 'four'
...

data=urlencode(d)
print(data)
# one=one&two=two&three=three&four=four
```

This way the order of your dictionary would be preserved

Comment: This does not answer the question because it doesn't include the final part of how said OrderedDict can be passed back into urlencode.

Comment: You are right. I guess I missed that detail. Edited.